# Python lxml получение текста

Tags: python, lxml

Имеется HTML-текст:

```
<div class="sku">
    <span>код товара: </span>15540-1550-1551</div>
```

Как можно вытащить оттуда сам код товара? text не срабатывает

Пробовал удалить span

```
sku_span = sku.cssselect('span')[0]
    sku = sku.remove(sku_span)
```

Тоже не вышло

Получаю Html так:

```
def get_html (request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request)
```

Comment: `sku_span.tail`

Comment: @andreqmal не совсем понял, где это применять

Comment: В вашем коде, вон же вы сами `sku_span` показали

Comment: @andreymal sku_span = sku.cssselect('span')[0].tail?

Comment: @andreymal, Спасибо понял